# How should I fill an array of ints from a file using command line args? The size of the file and the no. of elements may vary

Tags: c, memory-management, command-line-arguments, filestream, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am really new to programming in C. I have an assignment where I have to fill an array of integers from a text file using command line arguments. The array should be able to take in all the numbers from the file. 
This is the segment of code that is supposed to do the above, but it fails. I still have to add error checking but I just need to know where I am going wrong, and if I am on the right path.

From what I know so far, I will have to use memory allocation to make my array dynamic. I have used ftell() to find the size of the file in bytes so I can allocate memory accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc > 2) {
        printf(stderr, "Error, too many arguments supplied.");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (argc == 2) {
        int *numArray = NULL; //pointer to integer

        FILE* inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END);

        // calculating the size of the file 
        int fileSize = ftell(inputFile);

        numArray = malloc(fileSize * sizeof(int));

        if (numArray == NULL) {
            printf(stderr, "Error: File is empty.");
            exit(1);
        }

        int num;
        int arraySize = sizeof(numArray) / sizeof(numArray[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &num);
            numArray[i] = num;
        }

        fclose(inputFile);
    }

}
```

If file contains: 67, 66, 353, 789, 2342, 
NumArray = {67, 66, 353, 789, 2342}

Comment: `numArray = malloc(fileSize * sizeof(int));` is allocating space for one integer for every byte in the file. i.e. you are allocating far more memory than you actually need. This in turn means your `arraySize` will be bigger than the actual number of ints in the file and so your read loop won't work as expected.

Comment: *I have used ftell() to find the size of the file in bytes so I can allocate memory accordingly however I am pretty sure its not the correct way.* --> your intuition is correct. You are opening the file in text mode (ie: seem to have a text file) so the size of the file won't give you a way to determine the number of integers. You'll need to either count them first, allocate memory, rewind the file, and fill the array. Or you'll need to use realloc to keep resizing your array as you run out of storage.

Comment: I feel like there must be a duplicate for this question.

Comment: The only way `fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END);` makes sense is if the file is a **binary** file. If the file contains text with any whitespace or delimiters, then the length of the file is irrelevant to the read of values from it and the initial sizing of storage. Simply allocate storage for `2, 4, 8 or 16` integers to begin with. Keep a count of the number read. `realloc` when you reach your limit, rinse, repeat until you hit `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `<fstream>` is a C++ header, do not mix C and C++.
- `printf(stderr, "Error, too many arguments supplied.");` should produce a warning about the type mismatch on its first argument. use `fprintf` to print to `stderr`.
- The file is open in text mode, not binary mode, so `ftell()` might not return the number of bytes in the file.
- file open failure is not tested.
- Allocating `fileSize * sizeof(int)` is overkill. The numbers are in text format, so at most `fileSize / 2` numbers can by found in the file, and likely much less than that.
- failure to allocate bytes does not mean the file is empty.
- You should reallocate the array as you read more numbers from the file. This allows also for reading from devices that are not seekable such as terminals and named pipes.
- `arraySize = sizeof(numArray) / sizeof(numArray[0])` does not compute the number of elements in the array because `numArray` is a pointer to an array, not an array. Furthermore you should just keep the number of actual numbers read, which is the final value of `i` in the `for` loop.
- you should test the return value of `fscanf()`: 1 means the conversion succeeded, 0 means invalid input is present, that cannot be converted to an integer, `EOF` means end of file, or possibly I/O error.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The program expects a single command line argument\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        int *numArray = NULL;
        size_t arraySize = 0;
        size_t arrayCount = 0;
        FILE *inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        int res, num;

        if (inputFile == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        while ((res = fscanf(inputFile, "%d", &num)) == 1) {
            if (arrayCount >= ArraySize) {
                size_t newSize = arraySize ? arraySize * 2 : 32;
                int *newArray = realloc(numArray, newSize * sizeof(int));
                if (newArray == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory for %zu elements\n", newSize);
                    exit(1);
                }
                numArray = newArray;
                arraySize = newSize;
            }
            numArray[arrayCount++] = num;
        }
        if (res != EOF) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input for element %zu\n", arrayCount);
        }
        if (arrayCount == 0) {
            if (res == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "File %s is empty\n", argv[1]);
            }
            fclose(inputFile);
            return 1;
        }
        ...  // do something with the arrayCount elements in numArray
        free(numArray);
        fclose(inputFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd also add to that, better to check `argc < 2` and handle the error for *too few* arguments, rather than throw an error for *too many*. Simply ignore the extraneous arguments (or warn and keep going).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: indeed a diagnostic for the missing argument is more important.

Comment: Why `exit()` from `main()`? C++-programmers see it, copy it and baaam.

Comment: @Swordfish: OK for that, I prefer `return` from `main` anyway. Yet why would `exit(1)` from `main()` cause a problem for c++ programmers apart from destructors not being called? and why would they naively copy code from a C topic?

Comment: *apart from destructors not being called?* – that! – *and why would they naively copy code from a C topic?* – cause we are lazier than C programmers ;)

Comment: @Swordfish: very funny! I guess laziness get punished sometimes... I'm lazy too but I prefer C.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks! The full assignment states that I have to take user input if only one argument is passed.

Comment: @AlistairAlva: if this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.